# GAE: Unicode JSON String Not Working in Multipart Post After Blob Upload

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, unicode, google-cloud-storage

To upload files to Google storage, I sent multipart POST request to the url returned by [create_upload_url(redirect_path)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/). The POST request includes files and a JSON string that I need to use in redirect_path.

If the JSON string has unicode character, then it will be broken after GAE forward the multipart POST request to me.

JSON String sent to upload url:

```
{"subject": "日文", "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAycjkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6ZCQw"}
```

JSON string after GAE forward the request to redirect_path

```
{"subject": "=E6=97=A5=E6=96=87", "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAyc=
jkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6Z=
CQw"}
```

The unicode becomes unreadable and the '=' and 'newline' are inserted unexpectedly.

Strangely, a shorter JSON string with unicode works fine.

```
{"subject": "日文", "tag_key": ""}.
```

Other points,

1. the problem only happens in production environment. I cannot reproduce in local development server.
2. Multipart POST request to redirect_path doesn't have the problem. The issue only occurs on posting to blobstore.create_upload_url.
3. I am using GAE standard environment, Python, Django, Django Rest framework, and Postman to test.

Please let me know if you think of any possible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string is being encoded with the [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) for transport because it contains non-ascii characters.  The [quopri](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html) module in Python's standard library provides the tools to handle this:

```
>>> import quopri
>>> foo = '{"subject": "日文", "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAycjkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6ZCQw"}'
>>> encoded = quopri.encodestring(foo)
>>> print encoded
{"subject": "=E6=97=A5=E6=96=87", "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAyc=
jkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6Z=
CQw"}
```

You can decode with `quopri.decodestring` to get the original string:

```
>>> print quopri.decodestring(encoded)
{"subject": "日文", "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAycjkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6ZCQw"}
```

The encoding is triggered by the presence of non-ascii characters in the json string; the newlines are being inserted because quoted-printable encoding enforces a line length of 76 characters.

You may be able to avoid this problem completely by escaping the the non-ascii characters in your json string - for example Python's json module does this [by default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage):

> If *ensure_ascii* is true (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the
>   output are escaped with `\uXXXX` sequences, and the result is a [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)
>   instance consisting of ASCII characters only.

```
>>> json.dumps({"subject": "日文", "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAycjkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6ZCQw"})    

{
    "tag_key": "ahNifnN1aXF1aS1kZXYtMTcwMDAycjkLEgRUZWFtIgtzdWlxdWlfdGVzdAwLEgdUYWdUeXBlGICAgICAgIAKDAsSA1RhZxiAgICAgK6ZCQw",
    "subject": "\u65e5\u6587"
}
```